# R, linear regression with duplicate data

Tags: r, regression

So I have an data set with

- customer ID
- Type Of customer service
- customer income.

I like to do linear regression, but a single customer ID can have multiple customer service. A costumer with 2 customer service will be put in two rows. How can I perform this type of linear regression?

Comment: I have search for duplicate and unique command but i don't think it will solve the problem

Comment: 1. Will the same customers at different customer service types have the same income? 2. What are you trying to explore (what do you mean by type of customer service)?

Comment: You should expect to have dependence within ID; you should perhaps consider  hierarchical / mixed models of some type. Which variable is your response?

Comment: If your question is specifically about R, then it is off topic here. But if it is about statistics, it's on topic.  So, I will vote to close, but if you remove the reference to R it can be reopened.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reformat your data. 
Say, F is your data, where you have n+1 different Types of customer service. You then make a dummy variable corresponding to using a particular type of service. The number of such dummy variables should be n, if the number of different Types of customer service is n+1. This is to avoid multicollinearity.

```
Customer_ID TypeOfService_1 TypeOfService_2 TypeOfService_n Customer_Income
1           1               0               0               1000.8
2           0               1               1               6000.9
```